# Object and Field Describe in Lightning Component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, picklist, describesobject, schema, describefieldresult

Is it possible to get sObjectDescribe in Lightning Components? 
In my case I need to have all possible values of picklist-field, but filter out the list of options conditionally.

Answer (score 2):

> You can do the describe call in the apex class and filter out the
>   value as you want and return those value to lightning controller:
>
> Adding a snap of the apex class method and lightning controller:

**Add the following in the Apex class:**

```
public class picklistWrapper {
    @AuraEnabled
    public String strValue {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled
    public String strLabel {get;set;}

    public picklistWrapper(String strValue, String strLabel) {
        this.strValue = strValue;
        this.strLabel = strLabel;
    }
}

@AuraEnabled
public static List<picklistWrapper> getPicklistValues() {

    List<picklistWrapper> lstPWrapper = new List<picklistWrapper>();
    Schema.DescribeFieldResult fieldResult = Account.BillingStateCode.getDescribe();

    for(Schema.PicklistEntry f : fieldResult.getPicklistValues()) {

        //write your logic to filter the values here
        lstPWrapper.add(new picklistWrapper(f.getValue(), f.getLabel()));
    }
    return lstPWrapper
}
```

**Add the following to the lightning controller:**

```
getInitialData : function(component, event, helper) {
    var action = component.get("c.getPicklistValues");

    action.setCallback(this, function(response){
        var state = response.getState();
        if(state === "SUCCESS") {
            var result = response.getReturnValue();
            console.log('=====result====',result);//you will get picklist values here
        }
    })
    $A.enqueueAction(action);
}
```

Comment: I definitely can, but want to simplify it and do not perform a call to server for this data

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do that in the lightning component itself

Comment: Currently you must fetch this metadata via apex. I suggest you use a storable action though. It's otherwise not available on the client.